# GIT How to pull changes between two tags

Tags: git, tags, release, pull

Is there any way you can pull changes made between two tags and not the full repository?

I would like to build an install script but only with changes between two points in time, which will be marked with tags.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No you can't. Git is a graph with each node with the diff from the previous node. You can `clone` the repo and `checkout` to a tag. Now you have all the data till that tag / commit. Now if you need to go to tag2, just checkout tag2 and now you have all the data (commit history) till tag2.

Comment: I wonder if you aren't asking what you really want. For example, suppose you have an install script file with 10 lines of code at Tag A. Assume 2 lines were added in the middle of the script file at Tag B. You are asking for just those 2 lines of code, but do you think the script will still work without the other 10 lines?

Comment: Your explanation is too vague and ambiguous. Please take the time to explain the full context with at least a simple illustration (in words is fine) of what you are trying to do.